# The url containing the # is truncated when tested with window.location.href in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, parameters

If the url contains a #, when I run console.log (window.location.href), you may get the string after the # and sometimes not.

I have tried console.log(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)) too.

But this method also produced the same result.

How do you always get the character after the # in IE?

No problem with chrome..

The url I tested looked like this:
http://aaa/bbb.html#param

Answer (score 0):

After getting the `location.href`, you could use the indexOf() method to check whether the url contains `#`, then using the substring() method to get the url without `#`.

Sample code as below:

```
  var href = window.location.href;
  if(href.indexOf("#")>-1){
      href = href.substring(0, href.indexOf("#"));
  }
  console.log(href);  //output: http://aaa/bbb.html
```

Comment: There are somtimes when 'location.href' may contain string after the # or not.
That's the problem I'm having. 

Comment: By using above code, we could get the url first, then check whether it contain `#`, if it contain `#`, we could use the substring method to get the url without `#`, if it not contains `#`, it will directly display the url. Please check it.